# Não consigo salvar uma consulta no Banco de Dados. Apresenta erro Unfortunately

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, android-studio

Estou a quase duas semanas com esse problema no meu código android, ja pesquisei em alguns fóruns e nada, então estou meio desesperado procurando ajuda. Sou novo mexendo com android, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Segue os códigos:

NovaConsulta.java:

```
public class NovaConsulta extends Activity {
    private Date data;
    private int ano, mes, dia;
    private Button dataButton;
    private EditText tipo_consultaET, dia_consultaET, localET,telefoneET,enderecoET,latitudeET,longitudeET,situacaoET,descricaoET;
    private Long id;
    private AvisaSusDAO dao;
    private CalendarService calendarService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nova_consulta);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        ano = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        dataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.data);
        tipo_consultaET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipo_consulta);
        localET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.local);
        telefoneET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefone);
        enderecoET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endereco);


        dao = new AvisaSusDAO(this);

        id = getIntent().getLongExtra(Constantes.CONSULTA_SELECIONADA, -1);

        if(id != -1){
            prepararEdicao();
        }

        calendarService = criarCalendarService();
    }

    private CalendarService criarCalendarService() {
        SharedPreferences preferencias =
                getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCIAS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nomeConta = preferencias.getString(NOME_CONTA, null);
        String tokenAcesso = preferencias.getString(TOKEN_ACESSO, null);

        return new CalendarService(nomeConta, tokenAcesso);
    }

    private void prepararEdicao() {
        ConsultaD consulta = dao.buscarViagemPorId(id);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


        tipo_consultaET.setText(consulta.getTipo_consulta());
        data = consulta.getDia_consulta();
        dataButton.setText(dateFormat.format(data));
        telefoneET.setText(consulta.getTelefone().toString());
        enderecoET.setText(consulta.getEndereco());

    }

    public void selecionarData(View view) {
        showDialog(view.getId());
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.data:

                return new DatePickerDialog(this, dataConsulta, ano, mes, dia);
        }

        return null;
    }




    OnDateSetListener dataConsulta = new OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int anoSelecionado, int mesSelecionado, int diaSelecionado) {
            data = criarData(anoSelecionado, mesSelecionado, diaSelecionado);
            dataButton.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + ano);
        }
    };

    private Date criarData(int anoSelecionado, int mesSelecionado, int diaSelecionado) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(anoSelecionado, mesSelecionado, diaSelecionado);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.consulta_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nova_consulta:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NovaConsulta.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.remover:
                removerConsulta(Long.valueOf(id));
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        }
    }

    private void removerConsulta(Long id) {
        dao.removerConsulta(id);
    }

    public void salvarViagem(View view){

        DatabaseHelper.Consulta consulta = new DatabaseHelper.Consulta();
        consulta.setTipo_consulta(tipo_consultaET.getText().toString());
        consulta.setDia_consulta(data);
        consulta.setTelefone(telefoneET.getText().toString());
        consulta.setEndereco(enderecoET.getText().toString());


        long resultado;

        if(id == -1){
            resultado = dao.inserir(consulta);
            new Task().execute(consulta);
        }else{
            resultado = dao.atualizar(consulta);
        }

        if(resultado != -1 ){
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.registro_salvo), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.erro_salvar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        dao.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask<ConsultaD, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ConsultaD... consultas) {
            ConsultaD consulta = consultas[0];
            calendarService.criarEvento(consulta);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

ConsultaD.java :

```
public class ConsultaD {

    private Long id;
    private String tipo_consulta;
    private Date dia_consulta;
    private String local;
    private String telefone;
    private String endereco;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String situacao;
    private String descricao;

public ConsultaD(Long id, String tipo_consulta, Date dia_consulta, String local, String telefone, String endereco,
                 String latitude, String longitude, String situacao, String descricao) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tipo_consulta = tipo_consulta;
        this.dia_consulta = dia_consulta;
        this.local = local;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.situacao = situacao;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        }

    public ConsultaD() {

    }

    public Long getId() {return id;}
public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

public String getTipo_consulta(){return tipo_consulta;}
public void setTipo_consulta(String tipo_consulta) {this.tipo_consulta = tipo_consulta;}

public Date getDia_consulta() {return dia_consulta;}
public void setDia_consulta(Date dia_consulta) {this.dia_consulta = dia_consulta;}

public String getLocal(){return local;}
public void setLocal(String local) {this.local = local;}

public String getTelefone(){return telefone;}
public void setTelefone(String telefone) {this.telefone = telefone;}

public String getEndereco(){return endereco;}
public void setEndereco(String endereco) {this.endereco = endereco;}

public String getLatitude(){return latitude;}
public void setLatitude(String latitude) {this.latitude = latitude;}

public String getLongitude(){return longitude;}
public void setLongitude(String longitude) {this.longitude = longitude;}

public String getSituacao(){return situacao;}
public void setSituacao(String situacao) {this.situacao = situacao;}

public String getDescricao(){return descricao;}
public void setDescricao(String descricao) {this.descricao = descricao;}



}
```

AvisaDAO.java :

```
    public class AvisaDAO {

    private DatabaseHelper helper;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public AvisaDAO(Context context){
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        if (db == null) {
            db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return db;
    }

    public void close(){
        helper.close();
        db = null;
    }

    public List<DatabaseHelper.Consulta> listarConsulta(){
        Cursor cursor = getDb().query(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TABELA,
                DatabaseHelper.Consulta.COLUNAS,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        List<DatabaseHelper.Consulta> viagens = new ArrayList<DatabaseHelper.Consulta>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            DatabaseHelper.Consulta viagem = criarConsulta(cursor);
            viagens.add(viagem);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return viagens;
    }

    public DatabaseHelper.Consulta buscarViagemPorId(Long id){
        Cursor cursor = getDb().query(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TABELA,
                DatabaseHelper.Consulta.COLUNAS,
                DatabaseHelper.Consulta._ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{ id.toString() },
                null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            DatabaseHelper.Consulta consulta = criarConsulta(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return consulta;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public long inserir(ConsultaD consulta){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_ENDERECO,
                consulta.getEndereco());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_LATITUDE,
                consulta.getLatitude());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.NM_LOCAL,
                consulta.getLocal());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.DM_SITUACAO,
                consulta.getSituacao());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_LONGITUDE,
                consulta.getLongitude());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_TELEFONE,
                consulta.getTelefone());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TIPO_CONSULTA,
                consulta.getTipo_consulta());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.DIA_CONSULTA,
                consulta.getDia_consulta().toString());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_DESCRICAO,
                consulta.getDescricao());

        return getDb().insert(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TABELA,
                null, values);
    }

    public long atualizar(ConsultaD consulta){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_ENDERECO,
                consulta.getEndereco());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_LATITUDE,
                consulta.getLatitude());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.NM_LOCAL,
                consulta.getLocal());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.DM_SITUACAO,
                consulta.getSituacao());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_LONGITUDE,
                consulta.getLongitude());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_TELEFONE,
                consulta.getTelefone());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TIPO_CONSULTA,
                consulta.getTipo_consulta());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.DIA_CONSULTA,
                consulta.getDia_consulta().toString());

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_DESCRICAO,
                consulta.getDescricao());

        return getDb().update(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TABELA,
                values, DatabaseHelper.Consulta._ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{consulta.getId().toString()});
    }

    public boolean removerConsulta(Long id){
        String whereClause = DatabaseHelper.Consulta._ID + " = ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{id.toString()};
        int removidos = getDb().delete(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.TABELA,
                whereClause, whereArgs);
        return removidos > 0;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper.Consulta criarConsulta(Cursor cursor) {
        DatabaseHelper.Consulta consulta = new DatabaseHelper.Consulta(

        );
        return consulta;
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String BANCO_DADOS = "Avisa";
    private static int VERSAO = 1;

    public static class Consulta extends ConsultaD {
        public static final String TABELA = "Consulta";
        public static final String _ID = "_id";
        public static final String TIPO_CONSULTA = "tipo_consulta";
        public static final String DIA_CONSULTA = "dia_consulta";
        public static final String NM_LOCAL = "local_consulta";
        public static final String VL_TELEFONE = "telefone";
        public static final String VL_ENDERECO = "endereco";
        public static final String VL_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        public static final String VL_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
        public static final String DM_SITUACAO = "situacao";
        public static final String VL_DESCRICAO = "descricao";

        public static final String[] COLUNAS = new String[]{
                _ID, TIPO_CONSULTA, DIA_CONSULTA,NM_LOCAL,VL_TELEFONE,VL_ENDERECO,VL_LATITUDE,VL_LONGITUDE,DM_SITUACAO,VL_DESCRICAO };

        public Consulta(Long id, String tipo_consulta, Date dia_consulta, String local, String telefone, String endereco, String latitude, String longitude, String situacao, String descricao) {
            super(id, tipo_consulta, dia_consulta, local, telefone, endereco, latitude, longitude, situacao, descricao);
        }

        public Consulta() {
            super();
        }
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TB_COMPROMISSO_APP (ID_COMPROMISSO_APP CHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                " DT_COMPROMISSO DATE NOT NULL, NM_LOCAL VARCHAR(300) NULL, VL_TELEFONE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, VL_ENDERECO VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL," +
                "VL_LATITUDE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, VL_LONGITUDE VARCHAR(30) NULL,DM_SITUACAO CHAR(18) NULL, VL_DESCRICAO VARCHAR(300) NULL");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TB_USUARIO_APP (ID_USUARIO_APP CHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                " VL_TELEFONE VARCHAR(30) NULL, VL_SENHA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, VL_EMAIL VARCHAR(30) NULL, NM_SOCIAL VARCHAR(300)" );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE TB_COMPROMISSO_APP;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE TB_USUARIO_APP;");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Erro:

```
06-01 09:39:45.974 4650-4650/br.avisasuscom.avisasus_v3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: br.avisasuscom.avisasus_v3, PID: 4650
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                              at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at br.avisasuscom.avisasus_v3.dao.AvisaSusDAO.inserir(AvisaSusDAO.java:90)
                                                                              at br.avisasuscom.avisasus_v3.NovaConsulta.salvarViagem(NovaConsulta.java:162)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: Erro Unfortunately ao clicar em salvar]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPt. Adicione a pilha de erros completa na pergunta.

Comment: pronto, coloquei o erro que apresenta no logcat, porque não apresenta nenhum erro aparentemente no código. E coloquei um print que é o que acontece depois que clica na função salvar, ao invés de gravar no bd apresenta essa mensagem

Comment: no seu log analise este trecho: 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at br.avisasuscom.avisasus_v3.dao.AvisaSusDAO.inserir(AvisaSusDAO.java:90)
at br.avisasuscom.avisasus_v3.NovaConsulta.salvarViagem(NovaConsulta.java:162)

coloque um breakpoint uma linha antes dessas linhas indicadas e veja se o método está recebendo os dados corretamente.

como não está tratando as excessoes do SQL você só conseguirá encontrar o que está indo errado para seu banco com debug

Answer (score 0):

Conforme apontado pela @Marcela Melo nos comentários, este erro ocorre pois há algum objeto nulo sendo acessado.

Para evitar este erro você deverá testar as propriedades antes de adicionar em seu `ContentValues`.

Exemplo:

```
public long inserir(ConsultaD consulta){
if(consulta == null){
return -1; // se estiver nulo, não poderemos adicionar
}
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
if(null != consulta.getEndereco()){
// adiciona apenas se não for nulo!
 values.put(DatabaseHelper.Consulta.VL_ENDERECO,
                consulta.getEndereco());
}
```

Isto deverá ser feito para toda as propriedades antes de adicionar ao `ContentValues`!

Comment: Fiz isso e continua alegando o erro Unfortunately..